# I am trying to collect large (14k) data from a Web page to my google sheet. IMPORTXML retuns me "exceed data volume" msg. How can I pass by it?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

This is the source of my query: https://www.municipiosefreguesias.pt/categoria/1303/Construcao-Civil-Empresas
This is the 1st XPATH I am looking for: /html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/article/div/div[3]/a

I got this XPATH using Inspect from WebSite (Chrome), then copying XPATH at the line I am looking for [Company Name], then I need the URL associated with it so that I can go inside and collect the other Phone and Email data. I will collect more data from this site, once this one works.

Comment: The link you've posted doesn't have a query in it. We're mostly unable to help if there isn't code to manipulate. If you can post your actual query, we can begin to point you in the right direction.

Comment: =importxml("https://www.municipiosefreguesias.pt/categoria/1303/Construcao-Civil-Empresas";"/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/article/div/div[3]/a")     This is what I have coded into the cell. The idea is to collect more data, once this will bring me a URL to use to collect the deeper data (phone, mail, address)

Comment: Haha. OH. You are importing that exact URL. I apologize for not understanding. So the page itself isn't too crazy, however if you open the source of that page, it is delivering 234K lines of HTML. That is a TON of information for a Google spreadsheet to parse. Are you in control of the data source, or only this spreadsheet? If you are, I'd create an API where you can chunk through the data a few hundred/thousand at a time, rather than all at once.

Comment: I tried to parse data with a script, but i confirm that the page is too large to do ! No solution except managing the source by itself !

Comment: This is super hacky and brute force-ish - copy the source code starting at <div class="col-lg-12 container">, paste it into a blank sheet (You might have to do this in chunks).  1) It will paste in as 2 to 3 columns.  Delete the mostly empty columns.  2) Highlight the range and sort it A - Z  ..  3) Delete everything that isn't the html for the link.  4) Use a combination of regex and SPLIT() to separate out the URL and the company name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.